# icheck-rails gem for Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am running with an Issue while integrating this gem, In [THIS](https://github.com/cubus/icheck-rails) url there is a section that says:

```
iCheck includes several skins, most of them with multiple color schemes. Include them like this:  
@import 'icheck/square/blue' 
@import 'icheck/square/green'
```

I tried to add above line in end of app/assets/stylesheets/application.css but the style are not effecting. Behind the scene Javascript is working fine and it rendering below given HTML:

```
<div class="icheckbox_square-blue" style="position: relative;">
    <input type="checkbox" data-color="blue" data-skin="square" class="icheck-me" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
    <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you see icheck stylesheets in browsers console?

Comment: @Mandeep, I figured out how to make iCheck Gem work in Rails 4, thanks for giving it a try to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make iCheck gem work in Rails 4 follow every thing that's mentioned in [THIS URL](https://github.com/cubus/icheck-rails) but do the below changes that I did to run it successfully:

Don't import in your stylesheet the way iCheck Gem doc say:

```
@import 'icheck/square/blue'
@import 'icheck/square/green'
```

In your application.css - add it this way:

```
 *= require icheck/square/blue
 *= require icheck/square/green
```

Comment: Ahh! import statements are for sass but looks like you were using css